# How to create synthetic fingerprint drawings

Tags: drawing, fingerprinting

I want to write a program that outputs synthetic fingerprint drawings that are indistinguishable from human fingerprints. I know the theory of fingerprints and what makes them unique. I don't know how the program should be doing the actual drawing. An idea that came to my mind is making the program start from a vector equation that resembles a fingerprint and randomize it by playing with constanst. Later it can use pySVG http://codeboje.de/pysvg/ for the actual drawing. How else can I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) for drawing.